# Reactive expression dependent on another reactive expression

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following type of code in my shiny application. This is not the exact code but just to give you an idea.

```
'shinyUI(
radiobutton("radio_c"),
UIOUPUT("hub"),
datatableoutput("contacttable")
)

shiny server(
output$hub <- renderUI({
   if(input$radio_c ==2){
    hub_list <- sort(unique(df_customer$Hub))
}
    selectInput("hub", "Hub", c("All", hub_list), selected = "All")
  })

output$contacttable <- renderdatatable({
if(input$hub != "All"{
###database operations}
datatable()

)}'
```

The code works fine with a warning "Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero". And before loading the datatable the warning appears in the application and then loads the datatable.

The reason I believe is that when the UI selectinput is getting updated the datatable calls for values and returns null hence giving the warning, but once the UI element is updated datatable is loaded and everything is good. But I don't want the warning to show up before loading the datatable. There should be some way where I can say shiny to load datatable only after updating the UI element.

I appreciate any ideas here.

Thank you

Comment: Haven't tested since your example is not reproducible, but you should be able to add `req(input$hub` between `renderDataTable({` and `if(input$hub != "All"{`

Comment: Perfect. That worked. Thank you so much